# selenium python how to read url from csv and convert list from pure string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, csv

I tried this code:

```
with open('products_url.csv', 'r') as read_obj:
    csv_reader = reader(read_obj)
    header = next(csv_reader)
    # Check file as empty
    if header != None:
        # Iterate over each row after the header in the csv
        for row in csv_reader:
            # row variable is a list that represents a row in csv
            print(row)
```

result:

```
['https://www.zzounds.com/item--RNEONE']
['https://www.zzounds.com/item--CVTGIGBARMOVE']
['https://www.zzounds.com/item--AKAMPCLIVE2XL']
['https://www.zzounds.com/item--RNETWELVEMK2']
['https://www.zzounds.com/item--AKAMPCONE']
['https://www.zzounds.com/item--NUMMIXSTREAMPRO']
```

But my expected result will be plain string not list.

```
https://www.zzounds.com/item--RNEONE
https://www.zzounds.com/item--CVTGIGBARMOVE
https://www.zzounds.com/item--AKAMPCLIVE2XL
https://www.zzounds.com/item--RNETWELVEMK2
https://www.zzounds.com/item--AKAMPCONE
https://www.zzounds.com/item--NUMMIXSTREAMPRO
```

How to get above result so I can use `driver.get(url)` in selenium python?

my csv look like this:

```
           url
https://www.zzounds.com/item--RNEONE
https://www.zzounds.com/item--CVTGIGBARMOVE
https://www.zzounds.com/item--AKAMPCLIVE2XL
https://www.zzounds.com/item--RNETWELVEMK2
https://www.zzounds.com/item--AKAMPCONE
https://www.zzounds.com/item--NUMMIXSTREAMPRO
```

Comment: `print(row[0])`?

Answer (score 0):

question is poorly worded.  consider an edit?

problem is you are printing the result to the console, rather than saving it in a list.  you can save it in a list by doing this:

```
with open('products_url.csv', 'r') as read_obj:
    csv_reader = reader(read_obj)
    header = next(csv_reader)
    # Check file as empty
    if header is not None:
        def _gen():
            # Iterate over each row after the header in the csv
            for row in csv_reader:
                # row variable is a list that represents a row in csv
                url, = row
                yield url
        urls = list(_gen())
    print(urls)
```

or you could use a list comprehension if you know the syntax

```
with open('products_url.csv', 'r') as read_obj:
    csv_reader = reader(read_obj)
    header = next(csv_reader)
    # Check file as empty
    if header is not None:
        # Iterate over each row after the header in the csv
        urls = [url for url, in csv_reader]
    print(urls)
```